# Psexec commands to remotely delete files in a few computers and looping of txt file

Tags: loops, scripting, cmd, remote-access, psexec

Hi I am New to scripting .
I have to remotely execute a PSEXEC command to delete al files in a certain drive in a few computers.
I do have a TXT file with every ip address of all the computers.
Is there a way to use PSEXEC to cmd command all the computers to delete the folders by executing every command for every IP in my txt file?
currently i am using this line whereby i need to manually enter the ip address in the command line for eg . PsTools>PsExec.exe \ 1.1.1.1 , 1.1.1.2 cmd /c rmdir /S /Q D:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /F %%i IN (FileWithEveryIP.txt) DO PSEXEC \\%%i CMD /C DIR folderToDelete
```

Use **%i** instead of **%%i** if you run it from command prompt window instead of batch file.

Replace **DIR** with **RMDIR /S /Q** if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. it worked. i could also open up programs and execute other commands to the list of ip with your syntax.